# Javascript: Passing variable from function to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, getelementbyid

I'm new to Javascript and I have a problem passing a variable from function to function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
    var filename = document.getElementById("Tagg").value;
    var checkboxesH = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="tags[]"]');

    checkboxesH.change(function () {

        $('input[type="text"][name="tags"]').val(filename);
        var current = checkboxesH.filter(':checked').length;
  });
});
```

in the checkboxesH.change function, filename is always null! why? When the page opens, there is a string in the textfield tags.
Thank you.

Comment: Any error in the console? does an input have the `id='Tagg`? What does console.log(filename) in the ready function print?

Comment: Looks like it should work. You should provide more informations. Just an advice for now: if you're using jQuery, stick to jQuery: use `$("#Tagg").val()` instead.

Comment: What sort of element is `"Tagg"`? Please show its html.

Comment: `filename` should contain the value of the field when the document loaded. If that value changes later, you have to read it from the field again with `$("#Tagg").val()`

Comment: The closing `});` for `$(document).ready(function () {` is missing. Add this to the last line.

Comment: Actually, when the page loads, I already have a string in the textfield... then i have a checkbox list, so when I check an item, the item should appear next to the string in the textfield separated by a space. but the problem is in the function change, i can't access to the value of filename, it's always null for some reason!

Comment: I didnt put all the code for the change function, I only want to know why filename is null

Comment: @nnnnnn it's an input type=text element

Answer (score 0):

Javascript passes the value of the variable at the time of the function creation.  To fix this problem you should simply call

```
document.getElementById("Tagg")).value
```

in your .change() function directly.  This way, it will reflect the state at change time, not when the change event handler was created.

Comment: Yeah but I just need the initial value of the variable, and use it everytime the change() function is called. It should be simple, there is a value in the textfield when the page loads that I want to store in the variable filename and use it in the change() function.